# Can't inject view in angular js using route

Tags: angularjs, web-deployment, angular-routing

Trying to inject view using route in AngularJS.When I click on the link it doesn't show the view in page.There is index.html file in which I am trying to inject view.

**This is index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Angular Routing</title>
    <!--<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="CustomStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body  ng-app="Demo">

    <table style="font-family: Arial">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="header">
                <h1>
                    WebSite Header
                </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftMenu">
                <a href="#/home">Home</a>
                <a href="#/courses">Courses</a>
            </td>
            <td class="mainContent">
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="footer">
                <b>Website Footer</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is module named script.js**

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/home", {
                templateUrl: "Templates/home.html",
                controller:"homeController"
            })
            .when("/courses", {
                templateUrl: "Templates/courses.html",
                controller:"coursesController"
            })
    })
    .controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Home Page";
    })
    .controller("coursesController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.courses = ["C#","HTML","JAVA","Angular JS"];
    })
```

When I click on one of the link say home, it displays this in browser address bar **http://localhost:51008/index.html#!#%2Fhome** instead of this **http://localhost:51008/index.html/#home**
And there is no error displayed in console[This is my Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbY2Z.png)

Comment: Have you tried without the hash in your `href`? i.e. `<a href="/home">Home</a>`.

Comment: Nope, I haven't. Bcs even in documentation it's written it should be used with hash. But still I will give a try

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Comment: According to [the official AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#examples), it should be `<a href="home">Home</a>`. Perhaps you can also try injecting `$locationProvider` and then calling `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`. Ensure you also have a `<base href="/" />` tag in your `index.html` file.